# Can't submit Alexa skill - interaction model (beta) tick is still grey. Model was built successfully

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I can't submit the Alexa Skill, because the Interaction model (BETA Builder) tick is grey - and therefore also the "Testing" tick is grey. But the model is always built successfully.

Do you have any idea what this might be?

Thanks a lot.
[Alexa portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Az9Wt.png)

Answer (score 0):

To enable 'Test' you should pass all other steps, which is below,

1. Skill Information
2. Interaction Model
3. Configuration

[image]